# Smart pointer memory pool

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, boost, smart-pointers

I'm using a third-party library which utilizes [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) for memory management.

The problem is that I need to allocate many objects and I have detected that the allocation and deallocation is rather resource-demanding. So I thought I should utilize a smart-pointer memory pool to reduce the overhead.

```
#include <boost/smart_ptr/make_shared_array.hpp>

template <class T, size_t pool_size>
class shared_ptr_pool
{
   boost::shared_ptr<T[]> pool;
   size_t avail = 0;

public:
   boost::shared_ptr<T> make_shared()
   {
      if (!avail)
      {
         pool = boost::make_shared<T[]>(pool_size);
         avail = pool_size;
      }

      return boost::shared_ptr<T>(pool, &pool[--avail]);
   }
};
```

The solution is to utilize [`make_shared` for arrays](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/make_shared_array.html) and the [`shared_ptr` aliasing constructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#aliasing_constructor). The solution in inherently thread-unsafe, but for my needs that is okay.

Any thoughts, comments or pretty much anything would be appreciated.

Comment: The main advantage of a pool is that released pointers can quickly be re-used. I don't see that functionality here. Once your pool is empty you need to re-create another pool.

Comment: This might be a silly question. But why would you use a third party library for something that is already in the language?

Comment: @Mads: The third-party library I use in turn use `boost::shared_ptr` because of performance, portability and it correctly uses `delete[]` on array types.

Comment: @LokiAstari: You are correct, this isn't a pool as such, as it doesn't return objects to the pool, but a chunk-allocator-thingy (?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the comments, this isn't really a "pool" because things don't go back into it when you're done using them. It's just an "incremental allocator" that does allocation in "chunks". A better name for it might be `shared_ptr_chunk_allocator` (and `chunk_size` instead of `pool_size`).

Given that `pool_size` is used only on the codepath that also allocates memory (so it's not a super speed-critical path where one more memory load would hurt performance), and `shared_ptr_pool<...>` has non-static data members (so there's no harm in adding one more non-static data member), surely it would make more sense to make `pool_size` a runtime parameter to `shared_ptr_pool`'s constructor.

```
// your current code:
shared_ptr_pool<myclass, 16> pool;
// versus my suggestion:
shared_ptr_pool<myclass> pool(16);
```

This would even allow you to provide a member function for modifying the chunk size on the fly, in case maybe your code could detect that its particular workload demanded a bigger chunk size.

```
if (memory_usage_low && still_spending_lots_of_time_in_allocation) {
    pool.set_chunk_size(pool.chunk_size() * 2);
}
```

The actual code implementation looks fine to me; nothing to complain about there. :)

You might be pleased to (or, you might already) know that `std::shared_ptr<T[]>` is part of the Library Fundamentals v1 Technical Specification, which I think means it *ought* to be coming to C++1z. However, it's not in the working draft yet as of N4567 (November 2015).